# FlatFileItemWriter should write output file named same as input file

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job that reads files matching naming pattern from a directory, does some processing, and writes back status of processing per line in input file. The writer must produce output files with same name as the input files. To the MultiResourceItemReader I pass the pattern: "files-*.txt" and expect the FlatFileItemWriter to use the name of the input file. How do I specify this constraint in context xml file ?

Reader bean

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
  <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters['cwd']}/#{jobParameters['inputFolder']}/file-*.txt" />
  <property name="delegate" ref="itemReader" />
</bean>
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">

        <property name="lineMapper">
          <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

            <property name="lineTokenizer">
              <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                <property name="names" value="paramA,paramB" />
              </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper" >
              <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                <property name="targetType" value="a.b.c.d.MyObject" />
              </bean>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I tried this: add the input file path as a string property to the ExecutionContext's map in my implementation of FlatFileItemReader. In my FlatFileItemWriter implementation - override setResource and actually create a Resource object out of value from ExecutionContext. Is this alright ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution can be produce wrong output because `MultiResourceItemReader` reads from first file a bunch of items and if this set doesn't match your completion-policy it reads from next resource; in this case you will have items from two different sources and `itemReader` bean is not synched to write to right output resource.
You can try to solve let `a.b.c.d.MyObject` implements [`org.springframework.batch.item.ResourceAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html) and write a custom multi-resource item writer and manage resource open/close when resource change (this solution is not trivial because requires state save for restartability, of course).

```
class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyObject>,ItemStream {
  private FlatFileItemWriter delegate;
  private String resourceName;

  public open(ExecutionContext e) {
    resourceName = e.getString("resourceName");
    delegate.open(e);
  }
  public close(ExecutionContext e) {
    e.putString("resourceName",resourceName);
    delegate.close(e);
  }
  public update(ExecutionContext e) {
    e.putString("resourceName",resourceName);
    delegate.update(e);
  }
  public void write(List<? extends MyObject> items) {
    for(final MyObject o : items) {
      String itemResource = o.getResource().toString();
      if(!itemResource.equals(resourceName)) {
        closeDelegate();
        openDelegate();
      }
      writeToDelegate(o);
    }
  }
}
```

Of course,this is not tested and it's just an idea.
Another way is quite different and simulate a loop using a [decider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html) in this way:

1. Create a bean (called `ResourceHolder`, for example) used to store resources from `file:#{jobParameters['cwd']}/#{jobParameters['inputFolder']}/file-*.txt`; this bean is not stored into execution context but filled with a JobExecutionListener at every job start because execution contexts should be stay small.
2. Use a decider to simulate a loop! from decider store into execution context the name of the current resource; also you need to store the index of current resource to move to next one or to stop your job
3. Read/process/write step use one single file,the one stored into execution context from decider

---

```
<batch:job id="job">
  <batch:decision decider="decider" id="decider">
    <batch:next on="CONTINUABLE" to="readWriteStep" />
    <batch:end on="FINISHED" />
  </batch:decision>
  <batch:step id="readWriteStep" reader="itemReader" write="itemWriter" next="decider" />
  <batch:listeners>
    <batch:listener class="ResourceHolderFiller">
      <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters['cwd']}/#{jobParameters['inputFolder']}/file-*.txt" />
      <property name="resourceHolderBean" ref="resourceHolderBean" />
    </batch:listener>
  </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
<bean id="resourceHolder" class="ResourceHolderBean" />
<bean id="decider" class="MyDecider">
  <property name="resourceHolderBean" ref="resourceHolderBean" />
</bean>

class ResourceHolderBean
{
  Resource[] resource;

  public void setResource(Resource[] resource) {...}
  public Resource[] getResource() {...}
}
class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
  ResourceHolderBean resourceBean;

  public void setResourceBean(ResourceHolderBean resBean){...}

  FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
    Integer resourceIndex = jobExecution.getExecutionContext().getInt("resourceIndex");
    if(resourceIndex == null)
    {
      resourceIndex = 0;
    }
    if(resourceIndex == resourceBean.getResources().size()) {
      return new FlowExecutionStatus(RepeatStatus.FINISHED.name());
    }
    else {
      jobExecution.getExecutionContext().putInt("resourceIndex",resourceIndex);
      // This is the key your reader/writer must use as inpu/output filename
      jobExecution.getExecutionContext().putString("resourceName",resourceBean.getResources()[resourceIndex].toString());
    }
  }
}
```

`ResourceHolderFiller` is a job listener that injects resources into ResourceHolderBean bean.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply @LucaBassoRicci. I used your first suggestion. Our maven project structuring restricts me to spring-batch-infrastructure version 2.1.9 so I wrote my own 'ResourceAware' kind of interface on a.b.c.d.MyObject.