# Spring Batch - Passing Resource Name from MultiResourceItemReader > FlatFileItemReader to StepExecutionListener

Tags: file-io, resources, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job that needs to do the below

- Check a directory on local file system that may contain more than one file
- Process each of the files, save data from those files to database
- Rename files by adding a suffix to include PROCESSED or ERROR

I have used the below

- A *MultiResourceItemReader* that reads files and delegates to a *FlatFileItemReader*
- The *FlatFileItemReader* reads data using *LineMapper*, *FieldSetMapper*
- An *ItemProcessor* manipulates data read
- An *ItemWriter* writes to the database

***What I want to do***

- Rename each file to either PROCESSED / ERROR at the end of Step based on execution status
- How do I pass the resource file name that the *FlatFileItemReader* processes to the *StepExecutionListener*?
- How do I pass the resource file name to the *ItemProcessor* as it also needs to save the name of the file the data was read from

Below is my relevant config

```
<batch:job id="myJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="processFiles">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" processor="myItemProcessor" writer="myItemWriter" commit-interval="100" />
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="myStepListener"/>
        </batch:listeners>                          
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: Currently reviewing Luca's suggestions and other ways of implementing this. Found that I can make my data object that needs to be mapped ResourceAware and the MultiResourceItemReader will inject the resource. That solves one of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623254/flatfileitemwriter-should-write-output-file-named-same-as-input-file/24625208#24625208).
I'm not a fan of first solution because is too messy and file rename is "hidden" into java code and can't be easily detected from job's xml definition.
I prefer solution #2: IMO success/error conditions are easy to check and step flow is more cleaner and well separated.
Get your consideration, I hope my advices will help.