# how Pass file name from file reader to file writer spring batch

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am reading multiple files from the folder. suppose file names are like test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt. I want to pass these file names to writer and to generated output file name like 'test1.xml' 'test2.xml' 'test3.xml.

Appreciate any help on this.

```
@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Value("classpath*:test*.txt")
private Resource[] inputFiles;

@Value("${fluent.ttrade.Location.Outbound}")
private String outPutLocation;
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemWriter<DeliveryOrder> multiResourceBlkdItemWriter() throws Exception {
    MultiResourceItemWriter<DeliveryOrder> multiWriter = new MultiResourceItemWriter<DeliveryOrder>();
    multiWriter.setDelegate(blkdItemWriter());
    String customerOutputPath = outPutLocation + "test1.xml";
    System.out.println(">> Output Path: " + customerOutputPath);
    multiWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(customerOutputPath));
    return multiWriter;
}


@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<trade> multiResourceBlkdItemReader() {
    MultiResourceItemReader<trade> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<trade>();
    reader.setDelegate(blkdItemReader());
    reader.setResources(inputFiles);
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<trade> blkdItemReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<trade> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    DefaultLineMapper<trade> customerLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

    FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "recordType"});
    tokenizer.setColumns(new Range[] { });

    customerLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
    customerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new MYFieldSetMapper());
    customerLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

    reader.setLineMapper(customerLineMapper);

    return reader;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean
public CustomStaxEventItemWriter<order> blkdItemWriter() throws Exception {

    //some code here

    itemWriter.setHeaders(listHeaders);
    itemWriter.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    itemWriter.setRootTagName("blkdFile");
    itemWriter.setFooterCallback(blkdFooterCallBack());
    itemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
    return itemWriter;
}

@Bean
public BlkdFooterCallBack blkdFooterCallBack() {
    BlkdFooterCallBack callback = new BlkdFooterCallBack();
    return callback;
}

@Bean
public BlkdItemProcessor blkdItemProcessor() {
    return new BlkdItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public JobExecutionListener listener() {
    return new EtradeResultJobListener();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<trade, order> chunk(2000)
            .reader(multiResourceBlkdItemReader())
            .processor(blkdItemProcessor())
            .writer(multiResourceBlkdItemWriter())
            .listener(blkdFooterCallBack())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(step1())
            .listener(listener())
            .build();
}
```

currently using my configurations i am writing all the test files to a single xml. Please suggest me the configuration to generate multiple files.

Comment: You can refer https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/spring-batch-partitionerreaderprocesorwriterhibernateintellij/

In that example, we store filename to ExecutionContext so you can reuse it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623254/flatfileitemwriter-should-write-output-file-named-same-as-input-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817659/spring-batch-passing-resource-name-from-multiresourceitemreader-flatfileitem

Comment: Luca Basso Ricci, I am not able to try the 2nd option.we will not have any job parameters.attached the configuration.can you please suggest how to pass filenames to multiresorcewriter.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch has an interface called `ResourceAware`.  In it, when using the `MultiResourceItemReader`, if the item being returned implements that interface, we will inject the resource the item came from.  This allows you to get all the information you'd need as to which file the item came from.  You can read more about this interface in the javadoc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html

Comment: Thanks Michel , I have implemented ResourceAware interface Trade Object.I am getting NullPointerException  in setResourceToDelegate() method in multiReourceWriter Class as i am getting null as resource . How to set the Resource name for MultiResourceItemWriter.I need a output file name same as input file

example : input file test.txt output file test.xml