# Is there a listener for MultiResourceItemReader for onResourceLoaded?

Tags: java, spring-batch

The requirement is to read from a log file and write into an XML file. 
The XML file should have name same(or similar) to the log file name.

Resources are set to MultiResourceItemReader using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver, FlatFileItemReader is used as delegate to the MultiResourceItemReader.

So if there is a listener to MultiResourceItemReader for new resource loaded, the new resource name can be injected to the XML writer. Please advice if there is a cleaner approach to decouple the reader and writer.

Comment: you want to read many (similar) files and create different output files from them? did you already look into https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/MultiResourcePartitioner.html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623254/flatfileitemwriter-should-write-output-file-named-same-as-input-file?rq=1