# Ability to read multiple files then write content per source file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Reading file is working good but writing file is not.

I would like to read multiple files then use `MultiResourceItemWriter` to write it separately, like:

Read Files:

```
source/abc.csv
source/cbd.csv
source/efg.csv
```

Should write files separate like:

```
target/abc.csv
target/cbd.csv
target/efg.csv
```

But currently it's putting all data in one file.

```
    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemWriter<FooCsv> multipleCsvWriter(@Value("${directory.destination}") Resource folder) throws Exception {
        MultiResourceItemWriter<FooCsv> writer = new MultiResourceItemWriter<>();

        writer.setResource(folder);
        writer.setDelegate(csvWriter(file));

        return writer;
    }
```

Note this is like copy and paste from source folder to target folder.

Comment: You haven't configured the max number of items per file so all the items are ending up in one.  To accomplish what you're looking for, you'll need to have the chunk end when the file ends as well.

Comment: How can configure the max number of items that matched to the source file? They don't have fixed number of rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FlatFileItemWriter should write output file named same as input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623254/flatfileitemwriter-should-write-output-file-named-same-as-input-file)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to this-

1. Write custom reader by extending multiresourceitemreader, then in read() method you can get your current source file name. Then set this file to your csvFoo and pass this source file name dynamically to you are writer.
2. Write one extra step and taskley which will list all your available source files then add them to jobparameter and pass both source and dest file name dynamically to next step and call this step in cycle until all list files are not proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MultiResourcePartitioner` to achieve the same. Here is sample Batch Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public MultiResourcePartitioner paritioner(@Value("#{jobParameters[srcDir]}") String src) throws IOException {
        Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(src);
        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        partitioner.partition(1);
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        return partitioner;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<String> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}") Resource file) {
        FlatFileItemReader<String> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<String>();
        reader.setResource(file);
        reader.setLineMapper(new PassThroughLineMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer(@Value("#{jobParameters[destDir]}") String dest,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}") Resource file) {
        String destFile = dest + file.getFilename();
        System.out.println(destFile);
        FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<String>();
        writer.setLineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>());
        writer.setResource(resourcePatternResolver.getResource(destFile));
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job kpJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("kpJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        Partitioner partitioner = context.getBean(MultiResourcePartitioner.class);
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").partitioner(slaveStep()).partitioner("step1.slave", partitioner).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep() {
        ItemReader<String> reader = context.getBean(FlatFileItemReader.class);
        ItemWriter<String> writer = context.getBean(FlatFileItemWriter.class);
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1.slave").<String, String>chunk(10).reader(reader).writer(writer).build();
    }

}
```

And pass `srcDir` and `dstDir` as job parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**simple solution to your problem** - why not just create Steps for each of the source file. Given that and based in your scenario, file source and target is one to one. `MultiResourceItemWriter` is just a way to create new output file once it reaches the limit you set `setItemCountLimitPerResource(int)` (that i dont find in your example).  You can even run the steps in parallel if you have any issue with performance, if there are no dependencies or sequence.